# Window/Application closes/crashes spontaneously(?) inside while loop (MonoDevelop Gtk# 2.0 app)

Tags: c#, monodevelop, ubuntu-16.04, gtk#

I was inspired by [this article on "worst volume slider designs"](https://www.designernews.co/stories/84443-redditors-design-worst-volume-sliders-possible) to create something similar myself. My small project seems to run fine initially, but after a variable number of seconds (usually within a dozen or so) after entering the `while` loop (see below), the application simply closes or crashes (I'm not sure which). This is my first time using MonoDevelop and Gtk#, although I do have some familiarity with C#. I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.

My `MainWindow.cs` is below, and all other forms are autogenerated with the `Gtk# 2.0 Project` template. Finally, my Window design has only 4 components: a Fixed container, a toggle button named `selectVolumeToggleButton`, and 2 labels named `lVolumeLabel` and `rVolumeLabel`.

There are no Errors or Warnings reported, the only indication I have that something is off is that `Build()` is sometimes (but not always) underlined with the message "Virtual member call in constructor". (Googling this did not help.)

I considered that `startIndex` may be getting too large(?), but replacing `startIndex++` with `startIndex = (startIndex + 1) % pi.Length` had no effect. (This also seems unlikely since the time to crash does not correlate with `sleepTime`.)

**Update:** A breakpoint placed on the closing brace of the `if` is not reached when the application "crashes".

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Gtk;

public partial class MainWindow : Gtk.Window
{
    public MainWindow() : base(Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
    {
        Build();
    }

    protected void OnDeleteEvent(object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
    {
        Application.Quit();
        a.RetVal = true;
    }

    const string pi = "3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510"+
                        "58209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679"+
                        "82148086513282306647093844609550582231725359408128";
    const int displayLength = 40;
    const int sleepTime = 100;
    Gdk.Color red = new Gdk.Color(255, 0, 0);

    protected async void OnSelectVolumeToggleButtonToggled(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (selectVolumeToggleButton.Active)
        {
            lVolumeLabel.ModifyFg(StateType.Normal, red);

            int startIndex = 2;
            string piLeft = pi.Substring(0, startIndex);
            string piRight = pi.Substring(startIndex, displayLength);

            while (selectVolumeToggleButton.Active)
            {
                lVolumeLabel.Text = piLeft;
                rVolumeLabel.Text = piRight;

                await Task.Delay(sleepTime);

                startIndex++;
                piLeft = piLeft[1].ToString() + piRight[0].ToString();
                piRight = piRight.Substring(1) + pi[(startIndex + displayLength - 1) % pi.Length].ToString();
            }

        }
        else
        {
            rVolumeLabel.Text = " <-- New volume set. Well done!";
        }
    }

}
```

**Update2:** I got a crash message to display.

```
*** Error in `/app/bin/mono': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x00007f0340003350 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x6da05)[0x7f035a5ada05]
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x77996)[0x7f035a5b7996]
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x7817e)[0x7f035a5b817e]
/app/lib/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0(gdk_region_intersect+0x6f)[0x7f035315f32f]
/app/lib/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0(+0x3d4f7)[0x7f035316a4f7]
/app/lib/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0(gdk_window_process_all_updates+0x118)[0x7f035316b048]
/app/lib/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0(+0x3e0a9)[0x7f035316b0a9]
/app/lib/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0(+0x1dd37)[0x7f035314ad37]
/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_main_context_dispatch+0x13a)[0x7f034bd3ac0a]
/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0(+0x48f88)[0x7f034bd3af88]
/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_main_loop_run+0xc2)[0x7f034bd3b2a2]
/app/lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0(gtk_main+0xa7)[0x7f035350aba7]
[0x41cdb804]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-007a2000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 10500774                           /app/bin/mono-sgen
009a1000-009a5000 rw-p 003a1000 08:02 10500774                           /app/bin/mono-sgen
009a5000-009d8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
027a9000-02c7e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
41a86000-41a96000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
41c35000-41d05000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0328000000-7f0328021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0328021000-7f032c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
...
```

There are another 175 lines of similar, I can include them if it's required.

Comment: what is the crash error?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, it just sort of closes as if I X'd the window manually. No errors anywhere. All of this is running with "Debug" btw.

Comment: @CodingYoshi I added an update in the OP with the crash message. TY

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is an exception. Try to run it from a terminal and look at the logs described there after launching.

Comment: Thanks for the message, I added an update in the OP with the crash message.

Comment: What about your mono version?

Comment: `mono` version is `5.0.1.1`. `MonoDevelop` is version `7.0.1 build 24`.